# Accounting for noncoverage in survey

Tags: survey, stratification

[I'm a stats noob, so please correct if I am going wrong somewhere!]

We run a survey of our customers based on certain events or touchpoints. The responses vary significantly by these touchpoints, so I would like to weight the responses by post stratification.

However, I have no responses from customers who didn't have an "event", and these customers make up more than 60% of the portfolio population! Is there a workaround to this problem - how do I accommodate for non-sampled segments in my analysis? Is imputation a possible solution?

For example:

Let us assume - we are a telephony services provider, and we survey our customers to find out how satisfied they are with certain elements of our service. We have oversampled customers with "dropped calls", because that is more of a "problem area". In addition, we randomly survey some customers who have 3G connections but do not have a dropped call.

Let's add some numbers to this - 1000 customers, 600 with 3G, 400 without. Of these, 100 customers with 3G have a dropped call, and 100 customers without 3G have a dropped call.

In our survey, let us assume we have responses from 150 customers - 50 with 3G and a dropped call, 50 with 3G and no dropped call, and 50 without 3G and dropped calls. If we wanted to understand how satisfied the portfolio of customers is, we could stratify the responses with the following weights:

```
Customers with 3G and Dropped call  (100/1000)/(50/150) = 0.3
Customers with 3G and no Dropped call - ((600-100)/1000)/(50/150) = 1.5
Customers without 3G and Dropped call - (100/1000)/(50/150) = 0.3
Customers without 3G and no Dropped call - ????
```

If we do not have responses from this segment, how would we extrapolate the survey to understand the portfolio's satisfaction?

The only thing I can think of is imputing responses from a few customers based on the responses from the other 3 segments - maybe there is a baseline response for a customer, given certain predictor variables, and the presence/absence of 3G and dropped calls will change that response for a given customer? This is an extremely vague idea and I am worried about adding responses to my survey which are "made up"!

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Statistical terms relevant to the situations you describe are "endogenous stratification" and "truncation".  A search for these in a statistics textbook or on the web may help.